# There is no parameter in setup.py for Required-By

Tags: python, setup.py

when I use bottom commend:

> pip show “package name”
> I see a parameter which is  "Required-By".
> how I can add this parameter in the setup.py file in my package?
> thank you

Comment: You don't - pip show <package> is showing you the top-level package caused the installation of the package you are showing. It is set at time of install by installing a top-level package.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks for a thing that does not exist; the reverse direction of `requires` is metadata established by the existence of a forward declaration; there does not exist any reverse-direction declaration.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This probably missed an `install_requires` in the package's `setup.py`. For example: If the package depends on `numpy`, then adding `install_requires=['numpy']` will make 'package name' show up for `pip show numpy`.

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes, as I read the question, the OP here is asking what you would add to numpy's `setup.py` to make it show as "Requried-By: SomeOtherPackage", not what you would add to SomeOtherPackage's setup.py to make it require numpy.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I agree with your take on what the question says, but I'd like to clarify what the question meant.